# Can you weight observations in a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, scikit-learn

Similar to a weighted regression, where each row of `[[variables],[output]]` has a weight associated with it, is there a similar version for, say a `MultilayerPerceptronClassifier`, where I can actually give it kind of prior probabilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and often done. However, it seems to me that it is not currently possible to do using scikit-learn. To certain extent you could simulate this by duplicating samples in the training and validation set to increase their weight, but it is certainly not an efficient way to achieve it.

If you plan using neural networks, I would recommend using some more advanced library such as TensorFlow, which has [`weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) loss function implemented. Using TensorFlow in combination with Keras might provide a beginner-friendlier interface, even though the learning curve may still be a little steep.

Alternatively, scikit-learn has [SVM classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit) that supports weighted samples, perhaps it could work for your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I would share a hack: copy data. This hack works on most models.

For example, if you find data point 1 is super important, make 5 copies of it. This hack can also be used to make the loss function more sensitive to certain class.

Comment: Sure! But more elegant and efficient would be to incorporate the weights directly into the loss function.

Comment: This hack is useless for large data sets, e.g. for images or audi data

Comment: My original dataset isn't crazy large but there is a very wide range of weights so if some observations have a weight of say 0.7 and some are in the range of of .05 then the amount of copies might get out of hand and take too many processors to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jan Kukacka mentioned, scikit-learn does not support `sample_weights` for the `MLPClassifier` learner.  However, the `skorch` package which wraps PyTorch neural networks to have the same API as `sklearn` has some support for it built in.  You can find more information on how to do it in [`skorch`'s FAQ](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch/blob/master/docs/user/FAQ.rst#i-want-to-use-sample_weight-how-can-i-do-this).